# how to manage pylons/paster config file in a cluster?

Tags: python, deployment, pylons, config, paster

I have 4 nodes running paster app, once I change the config, I need to change config files on the 4 nodes. It will be a headache if the nodes number growing.

I believe it should be a common problem for people who running paster on more than one machines, is there any solution for this?

or did I use it the wrong way? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.1/index.html

This common solution for managing and deploying apps on several instances by ssh/sftp

Comment: thanks a lot! just tried  fabric and it was great!   playing with it now.